# Removing array rows based on certain matches between elements

Tags: arrays, numpy

Consider the small sample of a 6-column integer array:

```
import numpy as np

J = np.array([[1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 5],
              [2, 6, 3, 4, 2, 6],
              [1, 7, 2, 5, 2, 5],
              [4, 2, 8, 3, 8, 2],
              [0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3],
              [2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3],
              [4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4])
```

I want to remove, from J:

a) all rows where the ***first and second PAIRS*** of elements are exact matches
(this remove rows like [***1,3,  1,3***,  2,5])

b) all rows where the ***second and third PAIRS*** of elements are exact matches
(this remove rows like [1,7,  ***2,5,  2,5***])

Matches between any other pairs are OK.

I have a solution, below, but it is handled in two steps.  If there is a more direct, cleaner, or more readily extendable approach, I'd be very interested.

```
K = J[~(np.logical_and(J[:,0] == J[:,2], J[:,1] == J[:,3]))]
L = K[~(np.logical_and(K[:,2] == J[:,4], K[:,3] == K[:,5]))]
```

K removes the 1st, 5th, and 7th rows from J, leaving

```
        K =  [[2, 6, 3, 4, 2, 6],
              [1, 7, 2, 5, 2, 5],
              [4, 2, 8, 3, 8, 2],
              [2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3]])
```

L removes the 2nd row from K, giving the final outcome.

```
        L =  [[2, 6, 3, 4, 2, 6],
              [4, 2, 8, 3, 8, 2],
              [2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3]])
```

I'm hoping for an efficient solution because, learning from this problem, I need to extend these ideas to ***8-column*** arrays where
I eliminate rows having ***exact matches between the 1st and 2nd PAIRS, the 2nd and 3rd PAIRS, and the 3rd and 4th PAIRS***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we are checking for adjacent pairs for equality, a differencing on `3D` reshaped data seems would be one way to do it for a cleaner vectorized one -

```
# a is input array
In [117]: b = a.reshape(a.shape[0],-1,2)

In [118]: a[~(np.diff(b,axis=1)==0).all(2).any(1)]
Out[118]: 
array([[2, 6, 3, 4, 2, 6],
       [4, 2, 8, 3, 8, 2],
       [2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3]])
```

If you are going for performance, skip the differencing and go for sliced equality -

```
In [142]: a[~(b[:,:-1] == b[:,1:]).all(2).any(1)]
Out[142]: 
array([[2, 6, 3, 4, 2, 6],
       [4, 2, 8, 3, 8, 2],
       [2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3]])
```

**Generic no. of cols**

Extends just as well on generic no. of cols -

```
In [156]: a
Out[156]: 
array([[1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 5, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 5],
       [2, 6, 3, 4, 2, 6, 2, 6, 3, 4, 2, 6],
       [1, 7, 2, 5, 2, 5, 1, 7, 2, 5, 2, 5],
       [4, 2, 8, 3, 8, 2, 4, 2, 8, 3, 8, 2],
       [0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3],
       [2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3],
       [4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4]])

In [158]: b = a.reshape(a.shape[0],-1,2)

In [159]: a[~(b[:,:-1] == b[:,1:]).all(2).any(1)]
Out[159]: 
array([[4, 2, 8, 3, 8, 2, 4, 2, 8, 3, 8, 2],
       [2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3]])
```

Of course, we are assuming the number of cols allows pairing.

Comment: Perhaps it might be nicer to use `axis=-1` consistently instead of `axis=2` and `axis=1`.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq It's just more precise. Becasue with higher dims, we would adding in more of *colons* anyway.

Comment: Your 2nd solution in particular is super efficient.  As a relative newbie, could you just  show it applied to the 8-column case? (ie: eliminating 1st-2nd matching pairs,  2nd-3rd matching pairs,  3rd-4th matching pairs)

Comment: @user109387 It works for any number of cols without any change in the code. Or do you want me to show that as a sample case run?

Comment: @user109387 Added.

Comment: Really nice solution.  It will help me in a few other areas as well.

Answer (score 3):

What you have is quite reasonable. Here's what I would write:

```
def eliminate_pairs(x: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    first_second = (x[:, 0] == x[:, 2]) & (x[:, 1] == x[:, 3])
    second_third = (x[:, 1] == x[:, 3]) & (x[:, 2] == x[:, 4])
    return x[~(first_second | second_third)]
```

You could also apply DeMorgan's theorem and eliminate an extra `not` operation, but that's less important than clarity.

Comment: If this were extended to, say, an 8-column array, where we have first-second, second-third, and third-fourth,   how would you handle the Return statement?

Comment: @user109387 At that point, I would swap over to something similar to Divakar's answer and just compare via slices after reshaping (which is necessary to impose a "pairing" structure).

Answer (score 1):

Let's try a loop:

```
mask = False
for i in range(0,3,2):
    mask = (J[:,i:i+2]==J[:,i+2:i+4]).all(1) | mask

J[~mask]
```

Output:

```
array([[2, 6, 3, 4, 2, 6],
       [4, 2, 8, 3, 8, 2],
       [2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3]])
```